# Possible to copy data from one s3 bucket to another via Hive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, presto, trino

How can I query one bucket via hive and copy the results to another bucket in s3?

I have a DDL setup to run avro queries but wanting to transfer the subset of results from my filter to a new bucket/location in s3.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement from one catalog in Presto to another.